# CSS Grid on Safari on iOS Hiding Images

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to set up a grid of images in my Angular app, and it works just fine on desktop, but on Safari on iOS the images do not show at all.

The CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  max-width: 750px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid > div {
  background: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
}

.grid > div::before,
.grid > div > img {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.grid > div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.grid-square {
  background-color: white;
}

.gallery-thumbnail {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image-description {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.image-footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .gallery-image {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="page-description-container">
  <div class="page-description-content">
    <app-page-title [titleSize]="1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-image"></i>
      Gallery
    </app-page-title>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<app-loading-indicator *ngIf="isLoading"></app-loading-indicator>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-square" *ngFor="let post of pixelfedPosts; let i = index">
      <img
        (click)="toggleModal(i, true)"
        class="gallery-thumbnail"
        [src]="post.media_attachments[0].url"
        alt="" />
      <app-modal [isVisible]="modalVisibilities[i]" (onClose)="toggleModal(i, false)">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img
            class="gallery-image"
            [src]="post.media_attachments[0].url"
            alt="{{ post.media_attachments[0].description }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-description" [innerHTML]="post.content">{{ post.content }}</div>
        <div class="image-footer">
          <app-date-display [dateToDisplay]="post.created_at"></app-date-display>
          <a target="_blank" [href]="post.url">
            View on PixelFed
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </app-modal>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Here's how it looks on iOS:
[image: iOS]

vs. Desktop:
[image: Desktop]

I've looked it up but all of the CSS I'm using *seems* to be supported on current iOS (and has for awhile), unless I'm missing something.

Here's the site: https://www.rardk.com/gallery

Comment: Are the images being loaded? Are there image tags there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check on iOS. But here's the link (added to the question): https://www.rardk.com/gallery

Comment: [here](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) you have the "caniuse" of grid

Comment: So it looks like there's still the known issue with Safari and CSS grid. It says supported but with a really big issue...hmm. So is there no way around that?

Comment: You can check with either the simulator, or an actual device connected to a mac and debugged through safari. You can also try Safari's Developer > Responsive Design Mode. And no, it doesn't say "supported but with a really big issue" - it doesn't do intrinsic sizes, so just add some sizes so safari doesn't need to add them for you.